# Generating dynamic XML from Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dynamic, xml-generation

```
Data:
name    phone           email       address   address1   address2 dateofbirth
John    111111111   john@email.com  Chicago    Illinois  Phoenix    
Mark    222222222   mark@email.com  London     

My code:
def convert_row(row):
return """<Document>
<Name>%s</Name>
<Phone>%s</Phone>
<Email>%s</Email>
<Address>%s</Address>
<Address1>%s</Address1>
<Address2>%s</Address2>
<DateofBirth>%s</DateofBirth>
</Document>""" % (row.name, row.phone, row.email, row.address, 
row.address1, 
row.address2,row.dob)
with open('out.xml', 'w') as f:
f.write('\n'.join(df.apply(convert_row, axis=1)))

Current output:
<Customer>
<Name>John</Name>
<Phone>111111111</Phone>
<Email>john@email.com</Email>
<Address>Chicago</Address>
<Address1>Illinois</Address1>
<Address2>Phoenix</Address2>
<DateofBirth></DateofBirth>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<Name>Mark</Name>
<Phone>222222222</Phone>
<Email>mark@email.com</Email>
<Address>London</Address>
<Address1></Address1>
<Address2></Address2>
<DateofBirth></DateofBirth>
</Customer>
```

Could anyone please help me how to remove only Address1 and Address2 tags when the value is null (e.g. customer Mark).  However empty dateofbirth tag must be retained though it's null.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Format code and the other parts properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def convert(row):
    row = row[row.notna()]

    out = ["\t<Customer>"]
    for c in row.index:
        out.append(f"\t\t<{c.capitalize()}>{row[c]}</{c.capitalize()}>")

    return "\n".join(out + ["\t</Customer>"])


out = "<Document>\n" + "\n".join(df.apply(convert, axis=1)) + "\n</Document>"
print(out)
```

Prints:

```xml
<Document>
        <Customer>
                <Name>John</Name>
                <Phone>111111111</Phone>
                <Email>john@email.com</Email>
                <Address>Chicago</Address>
                <Address1>Illinois</Address1>
                <Address2>Phoenix</Address2>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
                <Name>Mark</Name>
                <Phone>222222222</Phone>
                <Email>mark@email.com</Email>
                <Address>London</Address>
        </Customer>
</Document>
```

---

Initial dataframe:

```
   name      phone           email  address  address1 address2  dateofbirth
0  John  111111111  john@email.com  Chicago  Illinois  Phoenix          NaN
1  Mark  222222222  mark@email.com   London       NaN      NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej. However, I need 
    1) <DateofBirth></DateofBirth> also to be printed in the output though it's 
    null.
    2) The XML structure is not fixed and it will have multiple nested tags. (e.g. 
    <phone><work>1111111111</work><home></home></phone>)

There are more than 200 fields to be printed with multiple nested.

Comment: @Sri This is just an example how you can begin with XML generation. Of course, the specifics which need to be customized is up to you...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the empty tags after creation:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  
columns = ['Name','Phone','Email','Address','Address1','Address2','DateofBirth']
row = [['John','111111111','john@email.com','Chicago','Illinois','Phoenix',''],['Mark', '222222222', 'mark@email.com', 'London','','','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(row, columns=columns)
print(df.to_string(index=False))

xml = df.to_xml(root_name='Document', row_name='Customer', index=False, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

def rem (rem_list, root):
    """ Remove listed empty tags from root"""
    parent_map = {(c, p) for p in root.iter( ) for c in p}
    for (c, p) in parent_map:
        if c.tag in rem_list:
            p.remove(c)

sel = ['Address1', 'Address2']
for customer in tree.findall('.//Customer'):
    rem_list = []
    for empty_tag in customer.iter():
        if empty_tag.text == None and empty_tag.tag in sel:
            rem_list.append(empty_tag.tag)

    # Call remove function
    rem(rem_list, customer)
    rem_list = []

ET.dump(tree)

tree1 = ET.ElementTree(tree)
ET.indent(tree1, space= '  ')
tree1.write('customer.xml', encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Output:

```
Name     Phone          Email Address Address1 Address2 Dateofbirth
John 111111111 john@email.com Chicago Illinois  Phoenix            
Mark 222222222 mark@email.com  London                              
<Document>
  <Customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Phone>111111111</Phone>
    <Email>john@email.com</Email>
    <Address>Chicago</Address>
    <Address1>Illinois</Address1>
    <Address2>Phoenix</Address2>
    <DateofBirth />
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Name>Mark</Name>
    <Phone>222222222</Phone>
    <Email>mark@email.com</Email>
    <Address>London</Address>
    <DateofBirth />
  </Customer>
</Document>
```